# Magento 2 - product image in product description page is incorrect

Tags: magento-2.1, product-images, csv, import-products

I imported csv file to upload product image in magento 2. The upload image is displaying only in category list page and shopping cart page. In product description page a different image from uploaded one is displaying And that the same image displaying in magento admin product image section. why this is happens and how to resolve this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the below instructions to regenerate all the catalog images.

> Admin -> System -> Cache Management -> Flush Catalog Images Cache (bottom of the page)

Above one remove the cache folder from `pub/media/catalog/product/cache`, then run the below command to regenerate all the needed images

```
php bin/magento catalog:image:resize
```

Comment: Its is right but the things is after every csv imported base image and admin thumbnail issue is happens. Resize takes very long time more than 4 hours for 4k product. It may take long time when my catalog size increase.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the images store view wise. may be base image change store view wise...

Answer (score 0):

1- Please create a product manually in admin with 3-4 media gallery images.and check in frontend this product is showing correctly.

2- Now export this product and check all images column

3- Now compare your csv with this exported product. and match images column then correct your csv and import again.

Hope this will help you.